How to make a semicircle above line in matplotlib?
I am trying to reproduce following shape in matplotlib:

So I tried to decompose it into 2 straight lines and 2 semicircles. The two straight lines are quite easy to make, but the semicircles turned out to be quite a difficult task to achieve. So far I have following code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def get_line_equation(point1, point2):
    x1, y1 = point1
    x2, y2 = point2
    m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    b = y1 - m * x1
    x = np.linspace(x1, x2, 100)
    y = m * x + b
    return x, y
x,y=get_line_equation((2.283,439),(2.162,574))
ax.plot(x,y, '--',color='cyan',  alpha=0.5)
x,y=get_line_equation((2.317,514),(2.2,645))
ax.plot(x,y, '--',color='cyan',  alpha=0.5)

x_line = [2.162, 2.2]
y_line = [574, 645]

angle = np.arctan2(y_line[1] - y_line[0], x_line[1] - x_line[0]) * 180 / np.pi
plt.plot(x_line, y_line, color='blue')
# Calculate the center of the semicircle
center_x = (x_line[0] + x_line[1]) / 2
center_y = (y_line[0] + y_line[1]) / 2

# Calculate the length of the line segment
line_length = np.sqrt((x_line[1] - x_line[0])**2 + (y_line[1] - y_line[0])**2)

# Set the radius to half the length of the line segment
radius = line_length / 2

print (center_x, center_y)
print(radius)

# Create a semicircle patch
arc = Arc((center_x, center_y), 2*radius, 0.05, angle=angle, theta1=0, theta2=180, color='red', alpha=0.5)

# Add the semicircle patch to the plot
plt.gca().add_patch(arc)

ax.set(xlabel=r'g1', ylabel=r'A1')
plt.xlim(2.10, 2.40)
plt.ylim(370, 670)
plt.show()
plt.close()

And I have following plot:

Currently the semicircle is going to the left but I want it to go more as a continuation of the line. It might be also something to do with the fact that the units of the x-axis and y-axis are not the same, but I don't really know how to account for that.

If you resize your plot window, or you zoom inside your plot, your rectangle is no more a rectangle and your semicircles are no more semicircles. If you want to keep everything straight, you have to work with fixed axis limits. That said, how do you choose the four points that give you the rectangle that you need? If you start thinking about this problem, is not a trivial one...
